# PetaPoco stored procedure error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."}

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, petapoco

I'm using C# with TSQL and SQL Server 2005

I'm trying to use PetaPoco to return a dataset as a list of objects.  this is the code I'm using just now

```
var s = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Append("USE [BI] EXEC [dbo].[TestProcedure2];");
            var result =  db.Query<dynamic>(s);

var result2 = db.Query<dynamic>("USE [BI] EXEC [dbo].[TestProcedure2];");
```

I think the error message is a generic sql error for when petaPoco fails.

At first I was using a stored procedure with paramaters and the @ character was causing a problem, once that was fixed with @@ i started getting this error so I made a stored procedure with a simple select statement.  The procedure executes completely fine in Management Studio.

Using PetaPoco with select statements is fine and the data is mapped both to a dynamic or an object model completely fine.  I created a garbage SQL string and it returned the same error which is where I'm getting the generic error idea from.

This is the select I'm using which works fine

```
var dynTest =
                db.Query<dynamic>(
                   "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [BI].[dbo].[Managers] ORDER  BY [ConsecutiveDays] desc");
```

Comment: Not familiar with PetaPoco, but are you sure the error isn't caused by trying to execute "USE BI EXEC Testprocedure" as a single query?

Comment: It works in Management studio, I've rephrased the query about 10 different ways and they all work in management studio but fail in the C# code. the BI database is defined when using PetaPoco, but EXEC [dbo].[TestProcedure2] also fails

Comment: Sorry about that then. I thought maybe the Management Studio was smart enough to split the statement into two queries. If that's not it, I don't have an answer.

Comment: Have you used Sql Profiler to see what exactly is getting sent to the server?  Perhaps that might shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its trying to append the select clause in front of it.
If you put a ";" at the start of your query it won't try to append it.

Comment: You can also use EXECUTE instead of EXEC.

Answer (score 1):

PetaPoco assumes that you want to perform a SELECT and will infer one if you don't include one.
To avoid doing the automatic SELECT you should use:

```
db.EnableAutoSelect = false;
```

Prior to your query.