# Syntax for PetaPoco to return a list of deleted records (from PostgreSQL)?

Tags: petapoco

I have the working PostgreSQL (9.5) delete statement of:

```
delete from dx d using patients p 
where p.chart_recid = d.chart_recid 
and p.recid = 15478 and d.icd9_recid = 7574
returning d.recid
```

What is the correct call using PetaPoco? (I am trying to return a List of int from
the delete statement). Can it be done?

This does *not* compile:

```
List<int> deleted = db.Execute(PetaPoco.Sql.Builder
                    .Append("delete from dx d ")
                    .Append("using patients p ")
                    .Append("where p.chart_recid = d.chart_recid ")
                    .Append("and p.recid = @0 and d.icd9_recid = @1 ", (int)patient_recid, (int)icd9_recid)
                    .Append("returning d.recid")
                    );
                return deleted;
```

TIA

Solution: This works compliments of [PetaPoco stored procedure error “Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.”}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032956/petapoco-stored-procedure-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-from?rq=1)

```
List<int> deleted = db.Fetch(PetaPoco.Sql.Builder
                    .Append(";delete from dx d ")
                    .Append("using patients p ")
                    .Append("where p.chart_recid = d.chart_recid ")
                    .Append("and p.recid = @0 and d.icd9_recid = @1 ", (int)patient_recid, (int)icd9_recid)
                    .Append("returning d.recid")
                    );
                return deleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Db.Execute()** calls ExecuteNonQuery method and returns affected rows or (-1) on exception. I think it should be;

```
int deleted = db.Execute(PetaPoco.Sql.Builder
                    .Append("delete from dx d ")
                    .Append("using patients p ")
                    .Append("where p.chart_recid = d.chart_recid ")
                    .Append("and p.recid = @0 and d.icd9_recid = @1 ", (int)patient_recid, (int)icd9_recid)
                    .Append("returning d.recid")
                    );
                return deleted;
```

Comment: @ibudb  I need the record id's of all the deleted records -- not simply one value. i.e., I need something like int[], or list<int> ... :)